# Identifying & Adding values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
class Member {
    constructor (membershipType, pointsEarned) {
        this.membershipType = membershipType;
        this.pointEarned = pointsEarned;
    }
}
```

```
var John = new Member ('Gold', 1400);
var Luke = new Member ('Ruby', 250);
var Sam = new Member ('Gold', 3350);
var Kelly = new Member ('Diamond', 40200);
```

```
Output:
       ruby: 250
       gold: 4750
       platinum: 0
       diamond: 40200
```

What I am trying to achieve is adding the "pointEarned" values that are tied to the same "membershipType" respectively to be added together.

For example if there are 2 gold "membershipType", I would like to add both 1400 & 3350 together. Is there any way I could do that?

I have used for loop to loop through the "membershipType". However, I can't wrap my head around it still. This is the code I have tried but it does not make sense.

```
for (var i = 0; i < memberGroup.length; i++) {
                    if ("Ruby" == memberGroup[i]["membershipType"]) {
                        for (let x in memberGroup[i]) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                    console.log ("\t\truby: " + (subMemTypeCount["Ruby"] ?? 0));
                    console.log ("\t\tgold: " + (subMemTypeCount["Gold"] ?? 0));
                    console.log ("\t\tplatinum: " + (subMemTypeCount["Platinum"] ?? 0));
                    console.log ("\t\tdiamond: " + (subMemTypeCount["Diamond"] ?? 0));
```

Comment: You should add that loop code to your question so we can help.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. Hope it helps, but it does not make sense that was why I didnt include in

Comment: what is the memberGroup data ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: memberGroup data is a 2d array. var memberGroup = [John, Luke, Sam, Kelly];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and explain this without using your original code, just to try and keep things minimal.

So lets's forget having a class, as it's extra noise in the code for now. We can just as easily define an object literal:

```js
var John = { membershipType: 'Gold', pointsEarned: 1400 };
```

Without seeing your `memberGroup`, we can assume it's some sort of array, like:

```js
const memberGroup = [
    John,
    Luke,
    Sam,
    Kelly,
];
```

Looking at your code, we can see that you're looking to get out the sums for each type. It'd be nice to store thoes types somewhere so we know what we're looking for:

```js
const types = [
    'Gold',
    'Ruby',
    'Platinum',
    'Diamond'
];
```

Now we need to know how to get the sum for a given type:

```js
const sumForType = (type, members) => members
    .reduce(
        (currentSum, member) => {
            if (member.membershipType === type) {
                return currentSum + member.pointsEarned;
            }

            return currentSum;
        }
    );
```

[`Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a nice way of taking multiple things, and reducing them down to a single value.

So now, we can just get the sum for each type:

```js
const subMemTypeCount = types.reduce(
    (sumsForTypes, type) => {
        sumForTypes[type] = sumForType(type, memberGroup);
        return sumsForTypes;
    },
    {},
);
```

So, putting it all together, we get something like this:

```js
var John = { membershipType: 'Gold', pointsEarned: 1400 };
var Luke = { membershipType: 'Ruby', pointsEarned: 250 };
var Sam = { membershipType: 'Gold', pointsEarned: 3350 };
var Kelly = { membershipType: 'Diamond', pointsEarned: 40200 };

const memberGroup = [
    John,
    Luke,
    Sam,
    Kelly,
];

const types = [
    'Gold',
    'Ruby',
    'Platinum',
    'Diamond'
];

const sumForType = (type, members) => members
    .reduce(
        (currentSum, member) => {
            if (member.membershipType === type) {
                return currentSum + member.pointsEarned;
            }

            return currentSum;
        },
        0,
    );

const subMemTypeCount = types.reduce(
    (sumsForTypes, type) => {
        sumsForTypes[type] = sumForType(type, memberGroup);
        return sumsForTypes;
    },
    {},
);

console.log(subMemTypeCount);
```

Or, if it were me, I'd like to write it like this :

```js
const John = { membershipType: 'Gold', pointsEarned: 1400 };
const Luke = { membershipType: 'Ruby', pointsEarned: 250 };
const Sam = { membershipType: 'Gold', pointsEarned: 3350 };
const Kelly = { membershipType: 'Diamond', pointsEarned: 40200 };

const propEq = p => k => o => o[p] === k;
const prop = k => o => o[k];

const hasType = propEq('membershipType');
const getPoints = prop('pointsEarned');
const sum = (x, y) => x + y;

const sumForType = (...members) => type => members
  .filter(hasType(type))
  .map(getPoints)
  .reduce(sum, 0);

const getSumForMembers = sumForType(John, Luke, Sam, Kelly);

const typeSums = ['Gold', 'Ruby', 'Diamond', 'Platinum'].reduce(
  (p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c]: getSumForMembers(c),
  }),
  {},
);

console.log(typeSums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider having two classes - one that defines a Member, and another that defines a group of Members. You can then pass an array of new Member objects into `Members`, and use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over that array of objects to calculate the totals.

```js
class Members {
  
  // Assign the array of members to `members`,
  // and define some default types
  constructor(members) {
    this.members = members;
    this.types = ['Gold', 'Ruby', 'Diamond', 'Platinum'];
  }

  // Use the default types to create an object of key/value
  // pairs where each value is set to zero
  initaliseTypes() {
    return this.types.reduce((acc, c) => {
      acc[c] = 0;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

  getTotals() {

    // Use `reduce` to iterate over the `members` array
    // and add up the values for each `type`
    return this.members.reduce((acc, c) => {

      // Destructure the type and value from
      // the current object
      const { type, value } = c;

      // We pass in out intialised types object
      // as the initial reduce object (accumulator).
      // On each iteration we add the value to the 
      // object where the key matches the type.
      // Then return the accumulator for the next iteration
      acc[type] += value;
      return acc;

    }, this.initaliseTypes())

  }

}

class Member {

  // Assign each key/value pair to `this`
  constructor(member) {
    for (const prop in member) {
      this[prop] = member[prop];
    }
  }

}

const members = new Members([
  new Member({ name: 'John', type: 'Gold', value: 1400 }),
  new Member({ name: 'Luke', type: 'Ruby', value: 250 }),
  new Member({ name: 'Sam', type: 'Gold', value: 3350 }),
  new Member({ name: 'Kelly', type: 'Diamond', value: 40200 })
]);

console.log(members.getTotals());
```

Additional documenation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)